# In oracle how to know which data is deleted through application and which is deleted through query

Tags: oracle

In a database how to know which data is deleted through application and which is deleted through query

Comment: This is only possible if you have an auditing framework in place which assigns tokens to sessions according to their origins (say by setting values using [`dbms_application_info`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_appinf.htm) ). Out of the box the database is utterly agnostic about who or what issues DML.

Comment: All deletes are going to be through a `DELETE` statement.  And all such `DELETE` statements are going to come from some client application.  I'm guessing you are asking how to differentiate ad hoc deletes issued from `SQL*Plus`, SQL Developer, TOAD, etc. from deletes issued by your custom applications.

Comment: can i find which ip perform delete operation

Comment: @satya not unless you're specifically logging/auditing delete operations somewhere.